# What is the best way to exclude bank holidays on Python script?

Tags: python

I have a Python script that I use at work. The script looks into the data of the day before and then produce new output.

The data looks like below:

```
\data
 ...
 - \23122019\output.csv
 - \24122019\output.csv
```

The script is run every weekday. However, since we have bank holidays (ie. national days off work) on 25th and 26th December, I have to manually set the date of the previous output folder so the script can find the correct data file.

Is there any simple way to set the script up so these bank holidays are excluded automatically?

Comment: Creating a list of holidays and checking upon it on every run?

Comment: Lazy solution: refactor the filenames' date formats to YYYYMMDD. Then the most recent output folder is whichever one appears last alphabetically / lexicographically.

Comment: Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips on those articles.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a python set containing the bank holidays date for the year, and then you can run a check using the `in` operator. For example of python set:

```py
example_set = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
'a' in example_set # returns true
```